# parse output 2>&1 with php script

Tags: php, linux

I have an exec command I am using to make ffmpeg work.

```
$process = exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/cave.wmv -deinterlace 
-acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x320 -f flv /home/g/Desktop
/file.flv 2>&1 | php testing123.php") ;
```

**In testing123.php I use**

```
$h = fopen('php://stdin', 'r'); $str = fgets($h); fclose($h);
//topic removed

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO table
(id,status) VALUES(?,?)';
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt3->execute(array(rand(),$str));
```

However, as you may have guessed I get one database entry, only when the file initially executes from the exec command in the other file. **Is there a way to keep executing the file or something else so that the output fed to the file can be inserted into my database every couple seconds?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `while` loop. There are some examples in the [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) documentation.

```
$h = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

while ( ($str = fgets($h)) !== false )
{
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO ...';

  mysql_query($sql);
}

fclose($h);
```

One of the comments in the documentation suggests using `stream_get_line` instead of `fgets`. In case you're interested, here's the direct link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#86319.

Comment: beautiful buddy. I love you. Have been messing with this for a while. Just two more questions. What do you think of the efficiency of this? Let's say I had multiple scripts executing this process. Also, to control the interval of information being parsed, would you use sleep?

Comment: @Scarface - I don't see any problem with multiple scripts executing the same PHP script at the same time. As for controller the interval, I'm afraid that you don't have control of what. The information is being piped through your script so the `ffmpeg` binary would be the one that needs to sleep. There's nothing wrong with inserting as you read the lines. What you could consider doing is inserting the lines in an array and once `ffmpeg` is finished running, the PHP script could slowly loop through the array and insert the data into your database.

Comment: Well the reason I am doing this is for a progress bar. The reason I was worried about sleeping is because I thought it would save processing if I could sleep and delay the data but since that is not possible, I can just use a regex to sort through the information to get the progress and update a database entry. Would that be stressful on system?

Comment: @Scarface - I think that should be fine.

Comment: Francois, I actually had one more question. I noticed the output actually stops at Press [q] to stop, [?] for help (command line output)...Does this mean the file is only executing once?

Comment: @Scarface - I'm not sure what you mean by only executing once but your `exec()` call is only called one so it should only run once. I know some additional information should come after the line you posted but I don't have ffmpeg installed to try it at the moment.

Comment: The info that normally comes is just the progress so 1000kb 1200kb etc. That info comes on a constant basis after the execution. I only get the initial information right at the start. And then when the process is finished I get the ending information. So for some reason the information in between is not coming. Hmm weird.

Comment: Francois check this out. http://if.invisionfree.com/topic/5114807/1/ I can follow it up to when he says he uses ajax to pass the process handle. Can you think of how he would do this? How would you keep passing output?

Comment: @Scarface - What he's saying is that is using JavaScript to poll for the status of the conversion. One PHP script processes it and stores information in the database while another PHP script (this one accessible through your website) accepts a parameter and returns the status of a particular conversion request. So on his "status" pages does an Ajax (Google Ajax if you don't know what that is) request to the one script with some time of ID and the script tells it how the other is doing. Makes sense?

Comment: I know what ajax is because I have used it but I find it hard to envision. Let's say there are 10 conversions taking place. When checking stdin, how can you identify which is which? I assume you are saying a script sends a request and the other somehow checks the progress using a similar process to that you showed me.

Comment: @Scarface - What you do is the PHP script that processes the conversion inserts records and includes an ID (perhaps a movie ID and/or account ID). The AJAX is made to a separate PHP script which reads that database and queries for either an account ID or movie ID and returns the status(es).

Comment: Thanks again Francois, one more question...How do you make the current php script insert records on a time interval? Wouldn't it just insert records once? Once the exec() is made, that script would have to keep polling somehow. Do you use flush or something?